# How to unit test negation when there is multiple conditions?

Tags: unit-testing

I have this piece of code

```
function aFunctionForUnitTesting(aParameter)
    return (aFirstCheck(aParameter) && 
           aOtherOne(aParameter) && 
           aLastOne(aParameter)
    );
```

How can I unit test this ?

My problem is the following, let's say I create this unit test :

```
FailWhenParameterDoesntFillFirstCheck()
{
Assert.IsFalse(new myObject().aFunctionForUnitTesting(aBadParameter));
}
```

How do I know that this test is ok because of the first check (it might have failed because of the second or the third, so my function firstCheck might be bugged) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a different value of your parameter, that will pass the first check and fail on the second.

```
FailWhenParameterDoesntFillFirstCheck()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(new myObject().aFunctionForUnitTesting(aBadParameterThatPassesFirstCheckButFailsTheSecond));
}
```

Comment: So I have to make a lot of test : check when first is ok but second not, check when both are not ok, check when second is ok but first is not, check when both are ok, and then arrives the third check...

Comment: Yes, you need to write a test for each case. You might want to use test coverage report to identify parts of code that aren't tested yet.

Comment: Ok so if there is 4 condition, I have to write 16 tests, 5  condtions 32... Test coverage won't help here because many of my test will run the same code.

Comment: You don't need that many tests, as you don't have to test for 'first check failed, second succeeded'. Compiler is clever enough to know that if the first check fails there is no point in executing the others.

Comment: Code coverage can help you, cause it will show that ie. `aLastOne()` method is not executed during the test.

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to write all these cases. It depends on what level of code coverage you want. You can get 'modified condition/decision coverage' in four tests:
- all params ok
- one of each param failing the test

'Multiple condition coverage' requires 8 tests here. Not sure I'd bother unless I was working for Airbus :-)

Comment: That's what i'm doing, but I'm looking at my code and I'm thinking "well maybe this test is passing but it shouldn't"